# twitter update status with javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

how can I update my twitter status from a w3c widget using only http/css/javascript? this is a mobile based widget.

i have my own tweetbox already. what i want to do is when the 'tweet' button is clicked,  my twitter status will be updated. I have read about oauth and I find it difficult to understand and implement. I dont think cURL could be implemented with javascript either.. how else can this be done?

Comment: This cannot be done from a widget built on the W3C Widget spec. The Twitter API requires that the user be authenticated with oAuth.

Answer (score 2):

Despite my pessimistic comment, I've decided that there is a way to do this. If you authenticate the user with OAuth (there's no way around it) on a server, you can keep those tokens around and use AJAX posts from the widget to your server to make the updates to Twitter. Basically, you'd be using your server to do the heavy lifting, almost like a proxy.

Honestly, though, you still need to use OAuth at the end of the day. And frankly, there's no way to do that in a widget.